# Bootloader can't load Windows?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, hard-drive, bootloader

I am using Windows 7 and it's installed on `Local Disk C`. I also installed Linux on another Local Disk. Because of the lack of storage, I formatted the local disk of Linux and merged the space with `C`.

Now, when I turn on the computer, it just restarts continuously.

Is there a way to solve it?

Note that the Windows files exist on the hard drive, its label is `Local disk (G)`.

Comment: When you formatted your Linux system disk you broke Grub.  You will need to reinstall the Windows 7 bootloader to resolve this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ok, does repair solves this?

Comment: when booting do you see a "grub missing" error ?

Comment: @DEFCON1: No, there is no errors pop up on the screen, it just restart immediately

Comment: @KuraFaqir - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392 and http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-7-bootmgr-is-missing-resolved-using-winre/8bb148bc-8035-4847-9696-888f7a0a9720 and http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/ what is not clear is if we are talking about different partitions on the same disk or simply seperate partitions.

Comment: @KuraFaqir at first you mentioned that your windows installation was in c: drive but later on you told that it was on g: drive after you have done with merging.This led ramhoumd into a doubt whether you were talking about different windows partitions.(i hope so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error may be due to some issues with the  botloader. To fix boot loader you may try this.

Grab a Windows recovery media or installation CD and boot from it.On the installation media you will see an option to repair your computer.Click "Repair your computer" and you
can Open the Command Prompt, then type

> bootrec /fixmbr

into the Command Prompt  and then reboot your system.

This article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/) might help you achieve it.

Comment: This will not affect the data's, right?

Comment: no.this is used to solve any problems associated with master boot record and it does not affect data in another partitons.