# How to reinstall Windows MBR with no Windows listed?

Tags: windows-7, boot, grub, mbr, repair

There is nice article how to reinstall windows MBR:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

however there is a catch. I have Windows system, but when I go with repair mode it is not shown and as the effect I cannot repair it.

The repair software indicates that I would need the drivers I used when installing it, but I don't recall I had any disk with drivers.

Computer: MacBookPro, systems: openSUSE 12.3, Windows 7. Loader: GRUB.

*Clarification: GRUB works, Windows works, I would like to remove GRUB and install Windows mbr instead (that's all). The problem is, according to Windows install DVD (repair program) I don't have Windows installed, Windows is **NOT** listed (actually there is no system detected at all).*

Comment: may be this works ?http://superuser.com/a/644962/241659

Comment: @Ash  my Windows system is **NOT** listed. The repair program in order to repair anything has to know WHAT to repair.

Answer (score 0):

If you are booting from a rescue usb/disk, there should be a repair mode.

If your recovery partition is ok, you can also try to boot from there:

[How to Boot into a Recovery Partition in Windows](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-boot-into-a-recovery-partition-in-windows.navId-397923.html)

Comment: Yes, there is repair mode. According to MS I should choose "Windows" in the list. The problem is -- the Windows is **NOT** listed.